# Elegant Boolean LINQ Query flexible for Active = true or Active = true or false

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've got a LINQ query to return lookup data. A bool parameter is passed in called active.

I want to either return only the rows where active = true
OR
return all rows regardless of active status
Is there an elegant way to do this in the where clause of LINQ?

```
          return await (from p in db.PackSizeTypes.AsNoTracking()
          where p.Active == true
          orderby p.ID

          select new PackSizeTypeObject
          {
              ID = p.ID,
              Name = p.Name.Trim(),
              LastEditedDate = p.LastEditedDate,
              LastEditedBy = p.LastEditedBy,
              Active = p.Active
          }).ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to use a ternary operator in the where clause to provide this switch?

Comment: if you want true or all, isn't that just all?

Comment: Yes, but on a processing form it has to only show where active = true. On a configuration form it has to show where active = doesn't matter  :-)

Comment: I wonder how you decide wether you want to get just active entries or all entries? Is there a second parameter?

Comment: There is a way, but elegant LINQ doesn't mean elegant SQL. Actually elegant LINQ solution will generate bad inefficient SQL query. If you ask me, forget about elegancy and go with conditional `Where`.

Comment: Inefficient SQL is 'okay' for this because the lookup table has less than 20 entries in it and is unlikely to ever exceed that amount of rows.

Comment: Then use something like `where !activeOnly || p.Active` (assuming you have `bool activeOnly` parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 IEnumerable<PackSizeTypeObject> MyPackSizeTypeObjects(bool? isActive)
{

return await (from p in db.PackSizeTypes.AsNoTracking()
          where  p.Active == (isActive == null ? p.Active : isActive)
          orderby p.ID

 select new PackSizeTypeObject
      {
          ID = p.ID,
          Name = p.Name.Trim(),
          LastEditedDate = p.LastEditedDate,
          LastEditedBy = p.LastEditedBy,
          Active = p.Active
      }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - this works like a charm! Don't know why I didn't consider a null-able Boolean. Thanks folks!